# Возможно ли с помощью публичного STUN сервера организовать TCP соединение между двумя клиентами?

Tags: tcp-ip, tcp, nat

Собственно, суть вопроса в заголовке. Есть два клиента за NAT, с выходом в интернет. Возможно ли с помощью публичного STUN сервера как то свести их и организовать TCP соединение?

Comment: *Если бы вы хоть немного почитали про этот протокол, такого вопроса бы не возникло.*

Comment: Мне кажется, вы меня не так поняли. Допустим - есть сервер для хранения ip адресов и портов. Клиент за NAT подключается по UPD к STUN серверу, и получает свой внешний IP и порт, и сохраняет их на сервере, после чего этот клиент начинает прослушку какого нибудь порта по TCP. В это время другой клиент с сервера получает внешний IP и порт первого клиента, и конектится к нему. Я просто перевернув кучу документации, в том числе и англ, не могу понять до конца механизм. Везде говорится, что STUN сервер отдает внешние данные, но нигде не говорится, что после этого с ними делать.

Comment: Нет, это вы не можете понять того, что вам пишут прямым текстом. Читайте мой ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Протокол STUN работает только для UDP.

Comment: Хорошо, допустим мы проделываем те же самые действия, которые я описал выше, только соединять клиентов будем по UPD имея на руках данные с STUN сервера. Так работать будет?

Comment: @EduardGushchin будет. За исключением того факта, что STUN не отдает данные чужих клиентов, вам нужен дополнительный канал передачи сообщений.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: Есть какой то STUNT — «STUN and TCP too

Comment: @beatsspam именно что "какой-то": ваш комментарий - аж третий в выдаче гугла! :-)